# How to close a popup and redirect to an iframe?

Tags: javascript, redirect, iframe, popup, window.opener

I have a page that contains an iframe, and the iframe opens a popup.

This popup after submitting a form should close and reload the iframe that opened it.

The popup is closed and redirect by this way:

```
window.opener.location.href = "http://www.myweb.com/iframe.php";
window.close ();
```

This has worked for me while I've been working directly from the iframe but when I do it from the page that contains the iframe the iframe does not refresh.

So... how can I reload the iframe in that case?

Comment: What about changing its `src` attribute? (If changing to the same thing doesn't work, try adding a `?foo=bar` or another cache-breaker at the end.

Comment: You can to change the url of the iframe from the parent? [aka the page that has the iframe in its body?]

Comment: Try `parent.window.close();` or calling a function in the parent `parent.closec_click()` and define the close_click function in the parent page.

Comment: Does the iframe come from the same origin as the page? That is to say, are they from the same domain?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm doing what you mention, I have that example to simplify

Comment: @watson nope! the iframe content has a subdomanin. is this the problem?

Comment: Well, there is no way to access the DOM of an iframe if it doesn't have the same origin as the containing page.

Comment: @watson ok thank you. answer my question and i'll give you the upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is no way to access the DOM of an iframe if it doesn't have the same origin as the containing page. So in that case, you won't be able to tell if the form is submitted. You would have to edit the JS of the iframe page and have the popup reload that page when you submit the form.

```
window.opener.location.reload()
```